# Stored Procedure to convert MEDIUMBLOB to Array of Double

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, binary-data, temp-tables, stored-functions

I'm quite unfamiliar with stored procedures so have been struggling with this for quite some time now. What I have is a database with a table that has a column of MEDIUMBLOB.

This data is infact binary data, which is a string representation of my Double Array. The representation is purely that each 8 bytes corresponds to each value, padded with the null byte \00. So for example:

\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\F0?\00\00\00\00\00\00\00@\00\00\00\00\00\00\b@\00\00\00\00\00\00\10@\00\00\00\00\00\00\14@\00\00\00\00\00\00\18@\00\00\00\00\00\00\1C@\00\00\00\00\00\00\s@\00\00\00\00\00\00"@

Corresponds to:

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

I am able to programmatically with LabVIEW use Unflatten from String to retrieve my values so I've established that the data is stored correctly. I now need to levy this to a stored procedure which can return similarly.

Unfortunately this is where I've hit my road block, my two main struggles is: how to return a array since MySQL does not support arrays or lists; retrieving data from a select 'Data' from testtable into a variable of string I can then manipulate and hopefully use substring, string length and convert functions with loops to acquire my array.

Note: I am using a MariaDB database with the MySQL Connector and creating my procedure in Heidi.

This is my latest iteration which is an attempt at using Temporary Tables:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE or replace procedure get_values (IN RowNumber Integer, OUT Value DOUBLE)
DETERMINISTIC
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1(TSVals MEDIUMBLOB);
select `DATA` INTO T1 from prop_binary;
i number := 1;
  begin
    for r in TS_values loop
    b number := Length(r);
    c number := 0;
        REPEAT 
        Value = convert(substring(r,(c*8),8),double);
        i := i + 1;
        c := c + 1;
        UNTIL c > (b/8);
    end loop;
  end get_values;
```

I'm not necessarily looking for a direct answer, pointers to how one would do it and any materials to provide me with the understanding and skills I need would be helpful also.

Edit: I was previously attempted to use packages (which I'm also not familiar enough with) to define an array I could return out in my procedure, this seemed futile though so the current method is to simply ask for a specific value to return, but array of values would be preferred for the whole data set.